# Как сделать, чтобы переменная int увеличивалась каждую секунду?

Tags: c++, int

1. Есть переменная **int bal = 0;***
2. Есть cout который выводит этот bal.
3. Как сделать чтобы bal рос **каждую секунду** на 1 единицу ?
4. Какой **цикл** или что использовать?

Буду признателен за вашу помощь!

Comment: Может быть просто запоминать время начального момента и сделать функцию, которая при обращении к ней будет говорить, сколько секунд прошло между текущим моментом и стартовым?

Comment: [`std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) каждую секунду возвращает значение на `1` больше.

Comment: Вопрос - судя по принятому ответу - задан совершенно некорректно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для Вашей цели хорошо подойдет `std::chrono`.

Благодаря этой библиотеке Вы сможете узнавать нынешнее время и таким образом сравнивать, сколько прошло времени и каждую секунду прибавлять единицу к Вашей переменной.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    constexpr int stop_when_ten_seconds_elapsed = 10;
    int bal = 0;
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(; bal <= 10;)
    {
        auto current_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        if(current_time - start >= std::chrono::seconds(1))
        {
            system("cls");
            start = current_time;
            bal++;
            std::cout << "Time elapsed - " << bal << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Этот цикл закончит свою работу по истечению 10 секунд, в Вашей случае условия выхода может быть другим.

Comment: по моему ТС не это нужно

Comment: Как раз, всё подходит, но каждую секунду код создает строку со значением, а мне нужно, чтобы уже в имеющейся строке с переменной эта переменная изменялась на ++ каждую секунду, но код каждую секунду печатает строку заново.

Comment: @Emoyshen, действительно, не до конца понял, что Вы хотите именно одну строку менять. Исправил.

Comment: @Emoyshen system("cls"); - это специфичная для Виндовс команда очистки содержимого консоли, на других ОС она работать не будет

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не совсем понятен, но можно делать это с помощью отдельного потока

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

void incrementer(bool& flag, int& value)
{
    while(flag == true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        ++value;
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool flag{ true };
    int value { 0 };

    std::thread th(incrementer, std::ref(flag), std::ref(value));

    while (_kbhit() == false)
    {
        system("cls"); // Windows
        std::cout 
            << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) 
            << " " << value << std::endl;
    }

    flag = false;
    th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш вариант подходи под ответ, нежеле тот что отметил ТС

Answer (score 0):

Если вас интересует простое решение и вы привязаны к определённой платформе, то можно решить задачу следующим образом (пример для Windows):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    int bal = 0;

    while (true) //infinity loop
    {
        Sleep(1000); //delay for 1000 ms
        ++bal;
        std::cout << bal << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Для решения под Linux придётся использовать другую библиотеку и функция задержки будет тоже другой соответственно.

Comment: В linux вместо `Sleep(1000);` надо написать `sleep(1); // секунды ` или `usleep(1000000); // микросекунды`